# Equivalent of "lm" for irregular time series forecasting in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, lm, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a two column data frame corresponding to time series of the form (Date, Value). I want to predict future values of Value based on this data. I don't need anything fancy, just a quick and dirty one-liner to give me a rough sense of what is going on.

For linear models, there is a version of this in R: The `lm` function. It handles missing values gracefully and always returns something useful. I have been searching high and low for an "equivalent" of this for *general* (i.e. possibly irregular / missing values) time series, and have come up short. (For example, `forecast::auto.arima` requires regular spaced time series.)

While I have found some complex solutions that are tailored to special cases and specific models, I just want a quick and dirty one-liner version of `lm` for time series that will work out of the box (see below).

*If there is no such function, is there a short explanation for why? This seems like a problem that should have a famously simple R solution.*

Example use of `lm` for comparison:

```
df  <- read.csv("my.csv")
lm(y ~ x, data = df) # one-liner
```

Comment: Hi: I don't know what you consider simple but the kalman filter handles missing values. The irregular spacing can be dealt with by finding the smallest irregular step and then considering that step as your time unit. I haven't done this sort of thing but I bet if you google for something like "Using the kalman filter to deal with missing and irregularly spaced values" something should come up. Note that I wouldn't consider it is a simple implementaton though.

Comment: I missed the part about R. Once the dealing with the irregularly spaced data issue is dealt with, then there are many R packages that allow you to use the KF. dlm is one but there are many others. You can check out the cran time series task view for more. Some R KF packages may be more suitable for what you want to do compared to others so you might want to check cran  out before you do the googling that I suggested in the first comment.